# Why doesn't .NET 6 return a Problem Details when NotFound("string") is used?

Tags: c#, .net-core

When `NotFound()` is returned from a controller in .NET 6, we get a problem details response.

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "traceId": "00-60bdfb25101c693a3c61b756dc4e6328-26e16d71c0017014-00"
}
```

However, this is not the case if let's say we return a `NotFound("ID has not been found")` in the method.

It returns

```
ID has not been found
```

Is this because the Framework assumes that anything passed into a NotFound() will be an object and then be serialized?

Comment: That seems like a good assumption. Try passing more a more complex object (rather than a simple string) and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

It's [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#problem-details)

It says that the framework will

> generate a problem details response for all HTTP client and server
> error responses **that don't have a body content yet**:

The automatic creation of a ProblemDetails can be customized using any of the following options:

1. Use ProblemDetailsOptions.CustomizeProblemDetails
2. Use a custom IProblemDetailsWriter
3. Call the IProblemDetailsService in a middleware

Or you can just return from your controller for example:

```
return Problem(detail: ex.Message, statusCode: StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
```

Which will produce

```
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.5",
"title": "Not Found",
"status": 404,
"detail": "Item with id '73' is not found.",
"traceId": "00-7bd57b13a8d43d5a3bf7044065f21e9c-2d9518c3c1290074-00",
```